# Is it possible to run Nodemailer on client only (using React) without a backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

There's nothing definitive out there, so have to ask - is it possible to run Nodemailer on React only with no backend?

I'm hoping to avoid a backend since I'm doing everything else in the client, would be supurb if I can also handle a contact form in client only.

For context, I want to avoid libraries/services that may be able to see any posted form data. I've come across email.js, though it's tied to an account/email client that stored all emails.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. The easiest solution I would recommend would be a serverless solution that you can tie a mailing service to. Mailing services like Mailgun or SendGrid for example

Comment: Yes it does, thanks David, much appreciated.